# Drupal::entityQuery

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

This is the official Drupal::entityQuery function definition I found

```
public static function entityQuery($entity_type, $conjunction = 'AND') {
  return static::getContainer()
    ->get('entity.query')
    ->get($entity_type, $conjunction);
}
```

I also see that conditions can be added after the original query has been assigned to a variable

```
// original query
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
              ->condition('status', 1)
              ->sort('field_some_field', 'some_value');

// expand query with another condition
if (!empty($taxonomy_type)) {
  $query->condition('field_taxonomy_type', $taxonomy_type, 'IN');
}
```

- Is this the correct way to query for nodes that contain a particular taxonomy type field?
- How do I filter for nodes that contain a specific taxonomy term?

Answer (score 2):

- Is this the correct way to query for nodes that contain a particular
  taxonomy type field?

> \Drupal::entityQuery() is the correct approach, yes.

- How do I filter for nodes that contain a specific taxonomy term?

> Would you like to filter by the taxonomy term name? If so you need to get the taxonomy term ID and use that in your condition:

```
// Get an array of terms that have the name "foo".
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
  ->loadByProperties(['name' => 'foo']);

// Get the first term from the array.
$term = reset($terms);

// Get an array of nodes that reference the taxonomy term "foo"s ID.
$nodes = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('field_my_taxonomy_term', $term->id(), '=')
  ->execute();
```

All Drupal entity references are done via the entities ID, so you will always be using that as your condition.

Also, `entityTypeManager()` & `entityQuery()` are basically the same thing, just structured slightly differently, so you can use whichever one you find most convenient.

Comment: Thanks so much, [100pic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/69785/100pic)